# copying the image bytes and paste it in notepad and then saving it with the same image format

Tags: image

I am copying the image bytes and paste it in notepad and then saving it with the same image format. But when i am trying to open the image its saying drawing failed(This process is manual). But how does coping of bytes through java works?

Comment: which editor are you using to extract the byte?

Comment: i am opening the image with notepad and copying bytes

Comment: I just want to understand the concept